# PHP scripts halts at arbitrary point but shutdown functions still called, no logged errors

Tags: php, xdebug

Have a peculiar issue with a client running PHP 5.3.17 on Windows.

There's a script that runs every minute as a scheduled task. Every so often, the script gets part-way through processing something and then exits. There are no errors logged.

By looking through xdebug traces, the spot is never the same. We also see from the traces that the shutdown functions are still run. So it goes: Running normally, stops at some spot, runs shutdown functions to completion.

What could it be?

Edit: Could it be the OS actually killing the process? Would there be a log of this? Maybe some watchdog daemon thinking the process is using too much CPU so it decides to kill it?

Comment: can you post the script in question?

Comment: how do you know it has only got part way through? show us what it does

Comment: Have you checked `max_execution_time`?

Comment: did u add the most strict error reporting?

Comment: @Dreen it's not easily reproducible so I can't provide a sample that will be helpful.

Comment: @kalpaitch Like I mentioned, we used xdebug traces to see the point it gets to. The exact point it gets to changes "randomly" (at least, we can't see a pattern).

Comment: @JustinPearce One of the first things we tried, but has no affect. It's turned off, but we also played around with setting it to various values.

Comment: @iight Yes, the whole app is E_STRICT from start to finish

Comment: Have you ruled out the script chewing through all available memory?